# What does return 0xfe + ceil(x) return?

Tags: c#, c++, c, hex, ceil

As I understand, C should convert 0xfe to -2, so the return ought to be ceil(x) - 2 - but the function seems to return neither of those. What should `int m(double x){return 0xfe + ceil(x)}` return?

Apologies for this newbie question. I am not a C programmer in general.  Just learning about hex and C.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question - I am not a C programmer and just learning.

Answer (score 10):

In the C language, `0xfe` is a hexadecimal `int` literal.  Specifically, it is equal to `254`, so the result is the double-precision value `ceil(x) + 254.0`.

If you *explicitly* convert to `int8_t` or another 8-bit signed type, like so:

```
(int8_t)0xfe
```

then you *may* get the value -2, but this is not guaranteed by the standard.  This is because `0xfe` has the value 254, which is not representable in a signed 8-bit field, so the last rule in section 6.3.1.3 of the standard applies:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

**If you want the value `-2`, write `-2`**.

Answer (score 7):

`0xfe` is *not* `-2`, it is `254`.

If you want `-2`, use "`-2`" (or "`-0x02`" if you really want to use hex).

Comment: What if you convert it implicitly to unsigned char, like the post mentioned above? Would it be -2 sometimes?

Comment: @ina: No; an `unsigned char` is never negative.  If you converted it **explicitly** to `signed char` (or better `int8_t`), it will *probably* become `-2`, but the actual result is implementation defined.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `0xfe` **never** means -2. On the other hand, -2 can **sometimes** mean 0xfe (if converted, implicitly or explicitly, to `unsigned char`).

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers said, if you want -2, you should use -2.

It is correct that 0xfe can sometimes mean -2, but this is entirely dependent on the datatype the value is stored in. If you only write 0xfe it will be interpreted as an int, and mean 254. If you store it in a signed char (a byte, 8 bits with the range of -128 to 127), it should be interpreted as -2. In c/c++ this datatype is called *char*, I think C# calls it byte, but I am not sure.

Comment: Your "should" in the last sentence is actually implementation-defined. Correct C code will not use `(signed char)0xfe`.